# React Calendar that supports prices in the cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, npm, calendar

Sorry I have been hitting my head around this for a while, but can't find any answer!

Does anyone know a React Calendar that supports adding the prices within the cells ? I just want to display a simple calendar, with each cells having the day of the month and below the price for that month. That simple. (Kinda like this how google flights work but for individual months, https://www.google.com/intl/zh-CN/insidesearch/images/features/flights-calendar-v2.png)

There seems to be a lot of calendar implementations but none supports this out of the box, which I find it very odd.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I dont't know if this will help, but check this component.
[react-big-calendar](https://github.com/intljusticemission/react-big-calendar)

Can't customize alot so maybe you'll be able to do what you want with it